# Are eventParameters in gtag event required?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, event-tracking, analytics-events

Simple question, in a gtag event, can we do just this :

```
    gtag('event', 'generate_lead');
```

instead of

```
    gtag('event', 'generate_lead', {
     'value': '2',
     'currency': 'USD',
     'transaction_id': '1234'
    });
```

if i dont need the eventParameters ?

Comment: I've never worked with gtag, but none of those parameters are required for events in general, so I don't see why they would be required for gtag event triggers.